# Dynamically set HTML5 range slider min, max and step values?

Tags: jquery, html

How to dynamically set the max, min and step value dynamically for HTML5 range control?

```
<input id="slider" type ="range" min="0" max="300" step="20" value="100" />
```

I have used the following try but no luck for me

```
$('#slider').attr('min', 10);
$('#slider').attr('max', 100);
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit Esnard for edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

```
$('#slider').prop('min', 10);
$('#slider').prop('max', 100);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yLoa0cn3/)

Comment: Hi still the value is triggering from control Max and Min Prop is not assigned.

Comment: @SanthoseKumar I'm assuming that you are using jQuery, correct? Also, I did fail to mention that these need to be inside of the `$(document).ready(function() { ... code here ...});`. Otherwise the selectors will not work, and it will still use the HTML5 attributes.

Comment: @SanthoseKumar Not a problem, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by changing the code on server side by using the constant value for Min,Max and step.

**Answer Found:**
 var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = 'input id="slider" alt="Slider" title="Slider" type ="range" min="**'+Constant+'**" max="**'+Constant+'**" step="**'+Constant+'**" value="**'+Constant+'**" />';

document.getElementById('div').appendChild(div);

Thanks